flatten JSON with Spark SQL
Im trying to explode the JSON structure using the Spark SQL in databricks.
I have the below code. having trouble to explode the "operationalOrders" which normally is the "ArrayType" structure.
%sql
WITH data_level_1 AS (
    SELECT  
        get_json_object(`data`, '$.id') as ID,
        get_json_object(`data`, '$.shippingUnit') as shippingUnit,
        get_json_object(`data`, '$.operationalOrders') as operationalOrders
    FROM 
        orders
    WHERE 
        type LIKE '%YardOrder%'
),
data_level_2 AS (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        operationalOrders,
        shippingUnit,
        json_tuple(shippingUnit ,"id" ) as (ID_shippingUnit),
        json_tuple(operationalOrders ,"id" ) as (ID_operationalOrders)
        

    FROM 
        data_level_1
)
SELECT * FROM data_level_2

when I run this query I get the null values for the operationlaOrders column which is incorrect.
Difference between operationlaOrders and shippingUnit column is type of the strcutre. operationlaOrders is the 'ArrayTypeandshippingUnitisStructType`.
result of the above table looks like this

Any help appreciated.
JSON - all the data that needs to be exploded is under 'datacol. and that is being done withget_json_object`.
sample:
{
    "id": "fc2621da-c5b2-401b-8502-ae68c3b4a8c0",
    "pk": "fc2621da-c5b2-401b-8502-ae68c3b4a8c0",
    "type": "Operations",
    "data": {
        "id": "fc2621da-c5b2-401b-8502-ae68c3b4a8c0",
        "version": "\"5a019b48-0000-0d00-0000-6605c8720000\"",
        "shippingUnit": {
            "id": "15831b77-8d41-4b56-a895-bacfdc0ea622",
            "kind": "45GP",
            "number": "M214",
            "location": {
                "id": "5e1d23ad-75fa-48eb-9138-761b54a2ba05",
                "yardZone": "Warehouse D",
                "yardZoneType": "Warehouse",
                "block": null,
                "slot": null,
                "isLoadingDock": false
            },
            "formerLocation": null,
            "contentStatus": "Empty",
            "shippingLine": "MSC",
            "shippingUnitStatus": "In",
            "inAt": "2024-03-19T12:16:10.8015149",
            "availableForPickupAt": null,
            "isRejected": false,
            "rejectReason": null,
            "reusedAt": null
        },
        "operationalOrders": [
            {
                "id": "9d2c3af5-b618-44ad-a71c-a6a8f2d16e4e",
                "isActive": true,
                "customerCode": "E",
                "customerMainReference": "E114",
                "customerReferences": [
                    "Ex014/1"
                ],
                "orderId": "EB19031441",
                "orderParentId": "EUB190314",
                "orderType": "Outbound",
                "loadingUnloadingPlannedAt": "2024-03-14T06:52:53.6824746",
                "loadedUnloadedAt": null,
                "cargos": [
                    {
                        "product": "Plates",
                        "article": "DV009",
                        "configuration": "piece",
                        "lotBatch": "LOT1042",
                        "warehouseCode": null,
                        "gateCode": null,
                        "adrClasses": [],
                        "ghsClasses": [],
                        "matchingId": "d7b8bde4-8ea9-4306-b9ee-d23786743f31"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "_etag": "\"6501014e-0000-0d00-0000-660677860000\"",
    "ttl": -1,
    "_rid": "AIZHAN4hE6tbAwAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/AIZHAA==/colls/AIZHAN4hE6s=/docs/AIZHAN4hE6tbAwAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1711699846
}


You have to explode your array, then you can parse the structs in that array.

@Andrew yes, I got that point. Question how to? that what im struggling with

@Andrew my Array is recognized as string after the get_json_object , any idea how to cast it to arrary in order to explode?

@play_something_good, please attach to your question a short example of the JSON (in text)

this is how you would cast the string back to array type in order to explode it
%sql
WITH data_level_1 AS (
    SELECT  
        get_json_object(`data`, '$.id') as ID,
        get_json_object(`data`, '$.shippingUnit') as shippingUnit,
        get_json_object(`data`, '$.operationalOrders') as operationalOrders
    FROM 
        orders
    WHERE 
        type LIKE '%YardOrder%'
),
data_level_2 AS (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        operationalOrders,
        shippingUnit,
        json_tuple(shippingUnit ,"id" ) as (ID_shippingUnit),
        json_tuple(operationalOrders_extended, 'id') AS (id)
  

    FROM 
        data_level_1
        LATERAL VIEW
        explode(from_json(operationalOrders, 'array<string>')) AS operationalOrders_extended
)
SELECT * FROM data_level_2

